# Magento 2.4.3-p2 salesrule_coupon_usage is not updating after place order

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4.3, queue

I have 2 Magento Instaces one is Production site and another is for development . On development Instance the COUPON usage works fine but for production site it's not working at all .
When is run the following command the Coupon Usage is updates in table but this is not a solution.

`php bin/magento queue:consumers:start sales.rule.update.coupon.usage`

I tried almost everything
`

```
    'cron_consumers_runner' => [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'queue' => [
            'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1
        ],
        'max_messages' => 0,
        'consumers' => [
            'async.operations.all',
            'codegeneratorProcessor',
            'exportProcessor',
            'product_action_attribute.update',
            'product_action_attribute.website.update'
        ]
    ]
```

`

Please help me